# What's the difference between arccos(x) and sec(x)?

Tags: trigonometry, secant

I know this question was asked on this site, but I didn't understand the answer. Could someone give me the simplest explanation of this? (High school level explanation)

Comment: $\arccos$ is the functional inverse, while $\sec$ is the multiplicative inverse of $\cos$.

Comment: Did you do any research?

Comment: Yes actually. I have spent about 3 hours looking through my textbook and online and couldn't figure it out. I have ADHD and have trouble connecting the dots sometimes, so when my question gets downvoted, I feel discouraged from learning mathematical concepts that other people seem to feel is easy to learn. So if that was you who downvoted, thanks a lot for discouraging me from learning a subject I like. If it wasn't, then this is directed at those who downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are completely different.

$\sec x = \frac 1{\cos x} = 1\div \cos x$.  This is the multiplicative reciprocal, which is sometimes call the *multiplicative* inverse.

$\arccos x$ is the function so that if $x = \cos y$ then $\arccos x$ is "going backwards" to get $y$ for which $x$ is the $\cos y$.  so  $\arccos x$ is defined as: If there are any $w$ so that $\cos w = x$ then one of those $w$ will be between $0$ and $\pi$; we define $\arccos x$ to be that $w$.

This is called the *functional* inverse.

That is it.

THE END.

...........................

Still reading?  Well... this is probably why you got confused:

A *multiplicative* inverse of a value $K$ is a value $m$ so that $m \times K = 1$.  In other words $m = \frac 1K$.  We write the multiplicative inverse of $K$ as $\frac 1K$ but we also say $K^{-1}$ meaning $K$ raised to the negative $1$ power.  (Remember $a^{-m} = \frac 1{a^m}$.) This will cause trouble later.

So the $\sec x = $ the *multiplicative* inverse of $\cos x$ means $\sec x = \frac 1{\cos x}$. Now we can write $\sec x = (\cos x)^{-1}$ *!!!!!IF!!!!!!* we mean "the value of $\cos x$ raised to the negative $1$ power.

The *functional* inverse of a function $f(x)$ is a function $g(x)$ so that $g(f(x)) = x$.  And we often write the inverse function of $f(x)$ as $f^{-1}(x)$ but notice ***!!!!!! THIS IS VITALLY IMPORTANT AND YOU WILL !!!!DIE!!!! HORRIBLY !!!!!! IF YOU MISUNDERSTAND IT!!!!!!*** this does *NOT* mean $(f(x))^{-1}$ which is "the value of $f(x)$ raised to the negative $1$ power"; this, $f^{-1}(x)$, means "the function that 'reverses' $f$ and gets us back to where we started".

So $\arccos x$ is the *functional* inverse of $\cos x$.  That is to say, $\arccos x$ is the function where $\arccos (\cos x) = x$.  It "undoes" the $x \mapsto \cos x$ to get us back to $x$.  We can write $\arccos x = \cos^{-1}(x)$ *!!!!!!IF!!!!!!* we mean "the function that 'reverses' $\cos$" and we ***!!!!!ABSOLUTELY UNDER RISK OF !!!!HORRIBLE!!!! DEATH!!!!  !N!E!V!E!R! CONFUSE IT WITH !!!!!!*** $(\cos x)^{-1}$ meaning "raising $\cos x$ to the negative $1$ power.

It is VERY unfortunate that we use two very similar looking notation for two *completely* different concepts.  It causes a *lot* of confusion in students.

(Actually *logically* the concepts are similar.  $K^{-1} = \frac 1K$ undoes a *multiplication* whereas $f^{-1}(x)$ undoes a *function*.  They both undo and get you back to where you started but one undoes multiplication.  They other undoes a function.)

(I don't know.  Maybe I shouldn't have mentioned that and maybe that's just more confusing.  Forget I said anything.)

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing this up for me! I'm glad you explained every little detail. I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 3):

$\arccos(x)$ is the inverse function of $\cos(x)$ (restricted to the interval $[0,\pi]$)

$\sec(x)$ is the reciprocal, $\dfrac{1}{\cos(x)}$.

in otherwords, it is the difference between $f^{-1}(x)$ and $\dfrac{1}{f(x)}$.

Comment: Although, unfortunately, $f^{-1}(x)$ could be read as referring to either the inverse of $f$ or $(f(x))^{-1}$.

Comment: the notation of $^{-1}$ attached to something that isn't a number cannot be thought of in terms of arithmetic. Though it is easy to see why someone might confuse the two at first, since we *can* totally do arithmetic with function *values*, $f(x)$, that *are* numbers.

Comment: In algebra the latter is written $f(x) ^{-1}$ since division doesn't work in a noncommutative setting.

Answer (score 1):

$\arccos x$ is a value whose cosine is $x$, whereas $\sec x=\frac{1}{\cos x}$. The two kinds of "inverse" trigonometric functions can feel a bit esoteric when you're new to them, but let's pretend $\cos x=7x+12$. Then $\arccos x=\frac{x-12}{7}$ while $\sec x=\frac{1}{7x+12}$, which is clearly completely different.